# How SQL Server stores SQL statements inside stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powershell

I have a database where the number of stored procedure is very high. but there are number of stored procedures where I have not started the transaction at the stored procedure level.

Now I want to put the transaction for these stored procedures in an automated manner. Currently I am using PowerShell to do so.

But the problem is I can get the definition of the stored procedure but I am not able to get the individual SQL statements inside a stored procedure so that I can write some transaction rollback / commit condition

For example if the above transaction fail `@@errorcount <> 0 then rollback`

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this or is there any other method to do so? If I can split the SQL statements (which are inside a stored procedure) I can write some login in PowerShell to manipulate the stored procedure

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. I would not do this programmatically. It is extremely difficult to code logic that can make decisions about where the appropriate place to put these statements. That aside, the safest bet would be to tie into the query parser engine in Visual Studio and have it parse the procedure code and break it apart into separate statements.

Comment: Also, how comes that you have to *extract* the stored proc code from your database? You don't use a source code control system?

Comment: The addition of lots of BEGIN TRAN-COMMIT TRAN logic willy-nilly in procs often results in more blocking and can result in command time-outs and more frequent deadlocks. If a COMMIT is left out somewhere, transactions can be left open and never committed, until the connection is closed by some means (perhaps forcibly) and the work that was done is thrown away and lost. If you were programatically creating new 'boilerplate' CRUD procedures, that would be one thing but I have to put in a third (fourth?) vote. This isn't your best idea.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored as text, so to inspect or even alter the body as statements, you need a [parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76083/21567). You might [get somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787155/21567) using the parser that is also used by Visual Studio (`Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.dll` and [`Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.aspx)), which is available with your Visual Studio installation and can be [redistributed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/22/redist.aspx). I'm currently using them to check that certain SQL scripts don't contain any "disallowed" SQL statements (well, disallowed in my own context of course) and it seems to work.

Having that said, I would agree with the comment made by @RobertLDavis, that this is probably not as easy as it looks and better not done automatically. Besides, you *should* review all the changes afterwards anyway. Thus, you probably could have done them manually in the first place.